# How to get version of project in solution in VS2015 WPF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, version, projects-and-solutions

I have setup project and WPF project in my solution.

I want that the title of WPF project will show the version of the setup project?

Is there any way to code it using xaml only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public string VersionApp
{
    get 
    {
        if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
            return string.Format("v{0}", ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString(4));
        else
            return "v -not available-";
    }
}
```